# How do I add another function to the bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to add an 8ball function to my Discord bot, but when I tried to run the code, it said there was an Unexpected token ",". When I removed the comma, it then said there was an Unexpected token function. Here are the functions:

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt), function (doMagic8BallVoodoo)) {
    var rand = ['Yes', 'No', 'No, eat a dick.', 'YAS!', 'Ask again later.', 'shlap shlap shlap', 'Get mega memed, bitch.'];
```

And here is the 8ball command:

```
case '8ball':
    bot.sendMessage({
    to: channelID
    message: 'Flat Earth says:' + (doMagic8Ballvoodoo)));
    });
```

edit: I've done some changes to the code. I'm able to run the script now, but the bot responds to every command except the 8ball one. Here's all the commands:

```
            case 'flatearth':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'The earth is flat.'
                });
            break;
            case 'roundearth':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'You fool. You absolute buffoon. The earth is flat, you fucking plebeian.'
                });
                break;
            case '8ball':
}

function doMagic8BallVoodoo() {
    var rand = ['Yes', 'No', 'No, eat a dick.', 'YAS!', 'Ask again later.', 'shlap shlap shlap', 'Get mega memed, bitch.'];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
}
                };
         })
```

Edit 2: I've modified the 8ball code, this is what it looks like:

```
            case '8ball':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Flat Earth says:' (doMagic8Ballvoodoo())
}

function doMagic8BallVoodoo() {
    var rand = ['Yes', 'No', 'No, eat a dick.', 'YAS!', 'Ask again later.', 'shlap shlap shlap', 'Get mega memed, bitch.'];

    return rand[Math.floor(Math.random()*rand.length)];
            });
            break;
}
                };
         })
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, as I keep getting syntax errors (When I put this 8ball code into an editor, it says "Unexpected token )" on what would be line 11 in this section of code). I'm also uncertain about the placement of the 8ball function, should I have kept it with the other function or before the 8ball command or...?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. If you're talking about line 20, the token that *is* expected where the comma is is a `{`, because that first function expression needs a body with `{` and `}`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it. Thanks so much; the error about the comma's been removed, but now it's telling me there's an Unexpected token variable on line 21...

Comment: @sdgsgfsgsfg Your issues are primarily syntax-related. You'll want to review the `bot.on()` call and ensure that all of your parameters are of the correct type. This includes ensuring that you're not inadvertently closing your functions too early, forgetting `{`s or `}`s where they're needed, etc.

I encourage you to take your callback functions and store them in variables, then pass those variables in as parameters instead. This will greatly simply your code and make it easier to spot syntax errors.

Comment: I've been working on the code; I'm able to run it, but the 8ball command won't exectute at all. I can't send the code in the comments, should I make another hastebin?

Comment: @sdgsgfsgsfg It may be better to append an edit to your original question with the code. I'll be sure to check back in at some point to review it.

Comment: @B.Fleming I added the updated code to the question; what is it that I did wrong?

Comment: @sdgsgfsgsfg This appears to still be a syntax issue. Look at line 14 in the new snippet you added. You're missing the appropriate `bot.sendMessage()` call. If you simply forgot to include the updated call that was discussed earlier on, then you probably have `'Flat Earth says:' + (doMagic8Ballvoodoo)` instead of the necessary `'Flat Earth says:' + (doMagic8Ballvoodoo())` (my mistake for not pointing this out earlier). Continue to seek out syntax errors because these seem to be the recurring theme while your program logic seems to be fine otherwise.

Comment: @B.Fleming I've updated some and added it to this post. I'm pretty certain that everything wrong with this code lies within syntax issues, I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Ask yourself some of the following questions: Where should my `doMagic8BallVoodoo` function be defined? Where is the start of my `switch` statement and where should it end? What does that syntax look like with only the `case`s and `break`s, and what needs to be added afterward? What am I really trying to do when I used `bot.sendMessage()`--what kind of parameter am I passing and what should that look like? I feel like providing the answers would do you a disservice in the long run. Take the time to clearly understand your intent. You have all of the dots, you just need to connect them :)

Comment: @B.Fleming Thanks so much!! I fixed it and she's working now. ^ _ ^

Comment: Fantastic! Good luck with any future coding endeavors!

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are at lines 47 and 48. You need a comma at the end of line 47 and you need to remove the two end parens and semicolon from the end of line 48. You seem to also have one too many end parens near the end of line 20 as well.